# "have difficulty doing" vs. "have difficulty in doing"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/difficulty)

> She had great **difficulty finding** a job.
>
> UK: People with asthma have **difficulty in breathing**.

It seems that British English puts an extra "in" there while `difficulty + doing` are acceptable both in AmE and BrE.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4):

No, your understanding isn't correct. It's not really that there's a usage split between [***British English...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20difficulty%20breathing%2Chad%20difficulty%20in%20breathing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20difficulty%20breathing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20difficulty%20in%20breathing%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...and [***American English***...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20difficulty%20breathing%2Chad%20difficulty%20in%20breathing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20difficulty%20breathing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20difficulty%20in%20breathing%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

It's just that ***usage has changed over time*** (on both sides of the pond). I see no significance in the fact that the "crossover point" (when it became more common ***not*** to include the preposition) was apparently a decade or two earlier *in print* in the US than the UK.

I can't think of any contexts where it would actually be "incorrect" to either include or not include ***in*** between ***difficulty*** and the associated gerund / continuous verb, and I doubt many native speakers would notice if you always made the "less common" choice with that particular noun.

But with closely-related forms, such as *He had a problem [**in**] starting his car*, the unwanted preposition would be ***very*** noticeable, so I suggest learners avoid it in ***all*** such contexts.

Comment: These are very interesting graphs.

Comment: Most other Indo-European languages (incl Romance & Germanic, which are the main contributors to English) make far more use of ***inflection*** to modify (lexical or content) words, as a way of indicating the relationships between the various words in an utterance. English uses more ***function*** words (such as prepositions) to do the same job - but when the nature of the relationship is obvious (as in the construction under consideration here), we have a tendency to discard "unnecessary" prepositions.