# "Do you have a problem IN doing sth" or "do you have a problem doing"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. Do you have a problem **in** doing sth?
2. Do you have a problem **doing** sth?

Prepositions are always tricky and there are not helpful rules. Which one of the above sentences is correct? If both, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: As you say yourself, " there are not helpful rules." Actually, the most common *preposition* in your context is *have a problem **with** doing it*. But no preposition at all is [even more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&corpus=26&content=have+a+problem+with+doing%2Chave+a+problem+in+doing%2Chave+a+problem+doing&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20problem%20with%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20problem%20in%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20problem%20doing%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: (On the semantic front, I'm more likely to say *I had a problem **with** doing it* if I had moral scruples about the activity, where omitting the preposition might simply imply I faced some logistical / practical difficulties).

Comment: It's not much of an "answer". Personally, I think regardless of the preposition, asking *Do you have a problem [with something]?* is often condescending and/or aggressive, so maybe you should just avoid the construction altogether.

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250064/have-difficulty-doing-vs-have-difficulty-in-doing